# Bitmap glyph does not show up after adding in FontForge

Tags: linux, fonts, fontforge

I found this font [Dina TTF](https://sites.google.com/site/rickard234/filecabinet) which is originally a *.fon file for Windows.
This version is a TrueType with only three bitmap strikes: 11, 12 and 13.
Works like a charm in Netbeans.

Yet I am missing exactly one glyph, a left pointing arrow: [U+2190](http://unicode-table.com/de/2190/).
I added it in FontForge, but when I generate the TTF, move it to `~/.local/share/fonts/TTF` and update my font cache via `fc-cache -vf ~/.local/share/fonts/TTF` the new letter does not show up.
FontForge draws a green border around the new glyph and the background is crossed out, opposed to e.g the letter `A` which is not crossed out or framed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because none of the fonts in the package encode U+2190 in any of the (Unicode) cmap subtables.

Try this: select a cell that doesn't have the red 'X' through it, go to Edit -> Copy Width. Then select the cell for U+2190, Edit -> Paste Into. The red 'X' for U+2190 should go away. Then edit the bitmap for U+2190 and regenerate.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a bitmap font cannot provide a letter for U+2190, since a bitmap font is a Windows thing?

Comment: TrueType/OpenType fonts (TTF or OTF) can include "embedded bitmaps" and can use the OpenType mapping schemes. So yes, you can have a bitmap font with U+2190. Older bitmap-only formats such as FON cannot map Unicode directly, but there are mappings from those older schemes into Unicode.

Comment: U+2190 is not saved. I've tried it a few times now. This is what I do: Open Dina, change to 11pt, edit U+2190, generate, close FontForge, reopen Dina, check if glyph is there.

Comment: Try this: select a cell that doesn't have the red 'X' through it, go to Edit -> Copy Width. Then select the cell for U+2190, Edit -> Paste Into. The red 'X' for U+2190 should go away. Then edit the bitmap for U+2190 and regenerate.

Comment: Thanks man, that worked! Now I can create some other missing letters as well.